# Downloading multiple files with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to download a batch of about 50 single images, process and save them. What is the best way to handle a lot of downloads?

I know how to use QHttp to download a single file, but I don't know how to work with a list of files.

Comment: +1 for -1s ! I believe this is a badly asked question, but real one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QHttp is obsolete, use QNetworkAccessManager. Each GET, PUT, etc. returns a [QNetworkReply](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8/qnetworkreply.html) object you can use to wait for the results of the respective request. If that is not enough, you could write a small QObject-derived helper class that monitors the reply object for error(), finished() and readyRead() signals and handles the received data, e.g. by writing it to a file.